# Layout of window content is incorrect in case of Window.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, size

I made a simple example. There is a tool window. It has Grid as the content with three areas. The first area is TextBox with some text, the second one is Label and the third is another TextBox. The heights of Grid's rows are respectively: "*", "30", "*". For the window I set `SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight`. When I open it The height of the first TextBox is bigger then the second one. When I try to reseize the window the heights become proportional as expected.

There is xaml of the window:

```
 <Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" MinHeight="200" MinWidth="200"
    DataContext="System.Data.DataSet" Width="291" d:DesignHeight="246"
    WindowStyle="ToolWindow"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBox x:Name="Text1" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="SOME TEXT"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="Text2" Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And code behind:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication5
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Text1.Text =
                "some text\nsome text\nsome text\nsome text\nsome text\nsome text\nsome text\nsome text\nsome text\n";
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: How to fix these jumping heights? Initially the heights should be proportional.

Initial Image :

[image]

After Resizing (what I want on load) :

[image]

Comment: Try setting `VerticalAlignment=Stretch` on your TextBoxes so they stretch to fill all available space in the Grid cell.

Comment: It did not help unfortunately. The first TextBox is still bigger at the moment of opening.

Comment: I don't suppose you could throw in a screenshot of the textboxes and 3 columns being run.
It may very well be that the Label in there with the textboxes is causing issues because Labels have padding that inflates their size - perhaps try setting the Label's padding property to "0,0,0,0".

Comment: @Logan I put the code in a test project and added some images. I didn't understand the question correctly either until I saw the output :)

Answer (score 1):

Your sample works as it should work.
Size is calculating from childs to root. So your TextBox has content with big height, then Grid makes first and third rows equal, then **Window.SizeToContent = "WidthAndHeight"** fit/minimize all sizes to size of their content.
Thus you see windows without free spaces.

When you trigger windows resize, the rule SizeToContent become false, because you manually set windows size and it could be recalculated. So Grids rows become equal size.

To check it you can:

1. remove SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" and you will see grid with equal rows height as you expected
2. or add e.g. KeyDown event like

   ```
   private void UIElement_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
       SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
   }
   ```

   So at the beginning Grid rows will have different size, after resizing, they become equal, **BUT** if you press any key, window immediately minimize his size and Grid rows will be not equal.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `SizeToContent` is applied *after* the initial grid is rendered. So the grid is initially calculated with with both textboxes of an equal size, then `SizeToContent` gets applied and resizes all controls to their minimum size.

As a way around it, you can apply a `SharedSizeGroup` to the Grid Rows so they are forced to be of an equal size when `SizeToContent` tries to resize everything.

```
 <Window ...
    WindowStyle="ToolWindow"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"  SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"  SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBox x:Name="Text1" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="SOME TEXT"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="Text2" Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then on initial load, it looks like this :

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works great, even with a Rectangle as the bottom "control".